# Can`t access to coturn web admin

Tags: webrtc, turn, coturn

I'm using Coturn on Centos 7.
I created an admin user and store in mySQL and I can list admin user by command:

> turnadmin -L -M "host=localhost dbname=turndb user=coturn
>   password=password port=3306 connect_timeout=10 read_timeout=30"

But I cannot login to Web Admin. Instead i see this message:

> TURN Server https admin connection
>
> To use the HTTPS admin connection, you have to set the database table
>   admin_user with the admin user accounts.

Why?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add web-admin web-admin-id web-admin-port to the configuration file.